# How can open the same modal from different states in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal, jhipster

i have an application generated using jhipster that have several views and a popup for shows the Product details. I need to open this popup from any view. The popup is open actually using angular-route in two pages specifying the parent, this work fine, but i need to open it for any pages in the application, and i think is not a solution repeat the state for every view in the application.

Comment: You mean angular-ui-router, right? Because this is what is used by JHipster not angular-routing. Anyway you could broadcast an event and open the modal in one place.

Comment: Thanks for answer. First, yes, you are right, is angular-ui-router, and second and don't get it your answer quit right, could you explain a little more please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018339/broadcasting-an-event-in-angular-how-to-alter-flow-by-subscribing-to-event

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a modal service for opening modals (for that specific entity).

Currently the modal logic is inside the XXX.state.js, as this is the only place, where JHipster uses it. Instead of injecting modal relevant dependencies in onEnter, like

```
onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
   //...
}
```

you should inject them into a distinct service, and expose an open method, and inject this service into the states, like

```
onEnter: ['MyEntityModalService', function(myEntityModalService) {
   myEntityModalService.open();
}
```

with these changes, you are initially not changing the frontends behavior, but decouples the logic into a service. As you now can inject in into the states, you can inject it anywhere else, too.